# How can I allow redirecting http to https in Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, https, firebase-hosting

I'm really not sure about this one. Firebase hosting is on https by default. How can I setup a default redirection for http to https ?

Thanks !

Comment: I just tested it on one of our domains: `http://firefeed.io/` and I get redirected to `https` automatically. I don't think anything is needed for that.

Comment: Thansk a lot ! You're right ! The problem only happens when I try to reach http url with www first. This has to be with my DNS settings right ?